# How to use a pop-up at the beginning of the ionic application?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm sorry for my bad english.

Still new to Ionic I create a simple application.

I would like to start the application with a pop-up but I don't know how to do it.

When you start a new application with Ionic, you can see at the end of app.js

> "*$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/accueil');*"

This is to begin the application on the page accueil, but I want to start with `"login()"` for exemple.

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution.

I solved my problem with this : http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/oCLJF

```
.factory('AuthService', function($rootScope) {
```

var loggedIn=false;

return {

```
checkLogin : function() {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('loggedIn', { 'loggedIn' : loggedIn });
  return loggedIn;

},

login : function() {
  loggedIn = true;
  $rootScope.$broadcast('loggedIn', { 'loggedIn' : loggedIn });
}
```

}

})

Thanks for your attention and help!

Answer (score 0):

I have used Ionic app and created a login page with angular router. Check my git code. https://github.com/gopinathshiva/ionic-chat-app/blob/master/www/js/app.js . Hope this helps

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your help!

This works fine but I want a Pop-up and in this way I have a html page.

I want to make a Pop-up like the ads for exemple.

Do you know a way to make this?

Thanks

Comment: You can use inbuilt ionic popup method to create popups